# Serializer not compatible to org.apache.avro.util.Utf8

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I was trying to do aggregation using kafkastreams, i was getting error as given below

Here is what i was doing:

```
KGroupedStream<String, Long> countrywiseAmount = ......;
KTable<String, CountSum> countrywiseAverageSum = countrywiseAmount
                .aggregate(new Initializer<CountSum>() {
                            @Override
                            public CountSum apply() {
                                return new CountSum();
                            }
                }, new Aggregator<String,Long,CountSum>() {
                    @Override
                    public CountSum apply(String country, Long amount, CountSum sumByCountry) {
                        sumByCountry.setCountry(country.toString());
                        sumByCountry.setCount(sumByCountry.getCount()+1);
                        sumByCountry.setSum(sumByCountry.getSum()+amount);
                        return sumByCountry;
                    }
                }, Materialized.with(stringSerde, countSumSerde));
```

The error i am getting is as below

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A
> serializer (key:
> org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value:
> org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer) is not
> compatible to the actual key or value type (key type:
> org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 / value type: java.lang.Long). Change the
> default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method
> parameters.
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:94)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:43)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:363)
> ... 5 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
> at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:28)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:162)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:103)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:89)

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with the KTable aggregation logic, but the issue with `KGroupedStream<String, Long> countrywiseChkAmount`, while creating it from `KStream<String, AvroModel>`, new KeyValue creation, the key should be converted from CharSequence to String. Thanks

Comment: You should mark your own answer as accepted.